# gSoap with multiple WSDLs with same operations

Tags: c++, soap, wsdl, gsoap

My client needs to be able to communication with both old and new server protocols (same endpoint), and because of that, I need to load 2 WSDL's with identical operations, but different namespaces (XML wise)

for instance:

```
<operation name="getServerTime">
   <input message="uc:GetServerTimeRequest"/>
   <output message="uc:GetServerTimeResponse"/>
</operation>
```

the wsdl2h seems to handle this fine. I run the command:

```
wsdl2h -p -o gSoap.h service2013.wsdl service2015.wsdl
```

and in gSoap.h I see it successfully parsed both operations well;

```
int __ns2__getServerTime(
    _common_2012_msgs__GetServerTimeRequest* common_2012_msgs__GetServerTimeRequest,    ///< Input parameter
    _common_2012_msgs__GetServerTimeResponse* common_2012_msgs__GetServerTimeResponse   ///< Output parameter
);

int __ns7__getServerTime(
    _common_2015_msgs__GetServerTimeRequest* common_2015_msgs__GetServerTimeRequest,    ///< Input parameter
    _common_2015_msgs__GetServerTimeResponse* common_2015_msgs__GetServerTimeResponse   ///< Output parameter
);
```

but the problem is afterwards, when I generate the proxy using soapcpp2:

```
soapcpp2 -jLCx -I$(gsoap_pkg)/share/import/ gSoap.h
```

the result in my generated proxy (soapCommonServiceSoapBindingProxy.h) only has 1 of the operations:

```
/// Web service operation 'getServerTime' (returns error code or SOAP_OK)
    virtual int getServerTime(_common_2015_msgs__GetServerTimeRequest *common_2015_msgs__GetServerTimeRequest, _common_2015_msgs__GetServerTimeResponse *common_2015_msgs__GetServerTimeResponse) { return this->getServerTime(NULL, NULL, common_2015_msgs__GetServerTimeRequest, common_2015_msgs__GetServerTimeResponse); }
    virtual int getServerTime(const char *endpoint, const char *soap_action, _common_2015_msgs__GetServerTimeRequest *common_2015_msgs__GetServerTimeRequest, _common_2015_msgs__GetServerTimeResponse *common_2015_msgs__GetServerTimeResponse);
```

I should also mention that before this, I tried to generate 2 seperate proxies but ran into endless linking issues due to ambiguous definitions of different structs (SOAP_ENV__FAULT and such). I tried to solve by manually namespacing stdsoap2.cpp and stdsoap2.h but different errors kept pouring in.

How do I successfully generate a proxy that supports both versions ?

Answer (score 2):

A)
You can use -qname with soapccp2, so that two services generate different soap files and namespaces.

for e.g.

```
soapcpp2 -j -n -C -w -qs2013 -I$(INC) service2013.wsdl
soapcpp2 -j -n -C -w -qs2015 -I$(INC) service2015.wsdl
```

You can refer to gSoap documentation for more details [gSOAP Code Namespace](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.35)

B)
For resolving namespace related linker issues, add the following code into a file (for e.g. namespaces.cpp), add to your project and compile.

```
#include <stdsoap2.h>
extern "C" {
SOAP_NMAC struct Namespace namespaces[] = { { NULL, NULL} };
}
```

C) For resolving linking issues related serialization and de-serialization functions, create an empty env.h file and compile it with the following command:

```
soapcpp2 -n -CS -penv env.h
```

add envC.* to your project and compile

Comment: This answer and the documentation are very helpful. An additional point from the documentation: after the changes in this answer, link both ClientLib files (or ServerLib), and DO NOT link soapC files, instead link the envC generated.